# Mongodb: how to update some elements and remove the rests of an array in an single operation?

Tags: mongodb

To an array I want to update some elements and keep array's size no great than N. How to do it in an single operation?
Lets' make an example to make my question clear:

```
1)db.test.insertOne({a:[1, 100, 3, 5, 600]});
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc5a14e1b800790b21afa65"), 
    "a" : [
        1.0, 
        100.0, 
        3.0, 
        5.0, 
        600.0
    ]
}
2) change it to
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc5a14e1b800790b21afa65"), 
    "a" : [
        1.0, 
        100.0, 
        5.0
    ]
}
```

As shown above, a[2]->5, and N=3, only keeps a[0],a[1],a[2]. I have to make these happen in one single operation to make data consistent(don't consider multiple clients)
How could I do ? Thanks!

Comment: What logic did you use to remove other elements?

Comment: I have an array object in memory respond to array in mongodb. After a couple of operations, I want to flush changes to db. In this situation, I know the elements  and the array's length to update, but don't know data in db's array. Of course, I can update the total array, while it seems not effective, since only part of elements changed

Comment: "Of course, I can update the total array, while it seems not effective,"
why do you think it's not effective? it depends on how often you will have a situation when you need to change only one element or no elements at all.
It seems like you over complicated this task because you want to achieve superminor optimization.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I'd recommend to follow this logic:

1. If the array in the memory has not been changed - do nothing.
2. If your array was changed and it's small then just update the whole array.
3. If your array was changed only a little bit and it's pretty big then calculate in your app what exactly elements were changed and create an update with corresponding operations for everyone (remove, update, insert). Be careful, it's an error-prone approach.

If your app runs into case number 3 "often", it means you designed a wrong data structure to solve your problem.